# Can a variable be initialized in Java without a type?

Tags: java, variables, types

Is there a way to initialize a blank variable without a type in Java and then later assign that variable a type?

Something that would look like this:

```
public class Main{

public void foo(Bar input){
    
    foo;
    
    (Bar) foo = input;
}
```

}

I want to know if there's a way to do what I want to do above in Java.

Comment: No, you can't do this, but if you can describe your _actual_ problem, there's another solution, probably generics.

Comment: This might give some hints: [Declaring a variable without specifying primitive type in Java OR changing an object to it's corresponding primitive type](//stackoverflow.com/q/31553242)

Comment: Java is a statically typed language ,you are bound to define a type

Comment: No. This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you hope to achieve by not declaring the variable type?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.  The closest you can do in recent versions of Java<sup>1</sup> is this:

```
public class Main{
    public void foo(Bar input){
        var foo = input;
    }
}
```

But this is significantly different to what you wrote:

1. The `var` keyword can only be used for a local variable, and only when the variable declaration has an initializer expression.  This does NOT work for a blank variable.
2. The variable (`foo`) does have a well defined (static) type.  But it is inferred (at compile type) from the static type of the initializer expression.  If the type inference doesn't work, that is a compilation error.
3. You can't get this to work with a dynamic type, as your example would seem to imply<sup>2</sup>.

---

The section of the Java 11 JLS that specifies `var` declarations is [JLS 14.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4).  It says:

> It is a compile-time error if the LocalVariableType is `var` and any of the following are true:
>
> - More than one VariableDeclarator is listed.
> - The VariableDeclaratorId has one or more bracket pairs.
> - The VariableDeclarator lacks an initializer.
> - The initializer of the VariableDeclarator is an ArrayInitializer.
> - The initializer of the VariableDeclarator contains a reference to the variable.

---

<sup>1 - Java 10 and later.

2 - For example, suppose that you had an `if ... else` and assigned different types in the branches.</sup>